# Handling Dates as IN Parameters of a MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

**What I want to Achieve**
I am creating a `Procedure` on my MySQL Database which will get the Total of the Net Amount column labeled as `netamt` where the Purchase Date labeled as `purdate` is between `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I tried two separate ways with my SQL Query. When I ran the `CREATE` Query, MySQL would accept it and create my `Procedure`. But, when I try calling the `Procedure` it returns `NULL`.

**My SQL Query**

Here is how my first `CREATE` code looks like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`*****`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Payable_Total_Net`(
  IN startDate DATE,
  IN endDate DATE,
  OUT totalNet DECIMAL(19,4)
)
BEGIN
 SELECT
    SUM(COALESCE(p.netamt,0)) INTO totalNet
    FROM Payables p
    WHERE p.purdate  >= str_to_date(startDate, '%Y-%m-d%') AND p.purdate <= str_to_date(endDate, '%Y-%m-d%');
END
```

Here is how my second `CREATE` code looks like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`*****`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Payable_Total_Net`(
  IN startDate DATE,
  IN endDate DATE,
  OUT totalNet DECIMAL(19,4)
)
BEGIN
 SELECT
    SUM(COALESCE(p.netamt,0)) INTO totalNet
    FROM Payables p
    WHERE p.purdate  BETWEEN str_to_date(startDate, '%Y-%m-d%') AND  str_to_date(endDate, '%Y-%m-d%');
END
```

This is how it looks as a normal query with the right result:

```
SELECT
SUM(COALESCE(p.netamt,0)) as totalNet
FROM Payables p
WHERE p.purdate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

This is how I call the `Procedure`:

```
Call Payable_Total_Net('2018-01-01','2018-12-31',@totalNet);
SELECT @totalNet;
```

**My Currently Stored Procedure**
[image: My Currently Stored Procedure]

**My Queries to call Stored Procedure**
[image: My Queries to Call Procedure]

**The Result if I run both queries at once**
[image: Result if Query All]

**The Result if I only run the Select query**
[image: Result if I Query Select]

**This is my expected result using the normal query**
[image]

Comment: How is purdate stored in payables table?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the values as dates.  You don't need to convert them:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`*****`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Payable_Total_Net`(
  IN in_startDate DATE,
  IN in_endDate DATE,
  OUT out_totalNet DECIMAL(19,4)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(p.netamt), 0) INTO out_totalNet
  FROM Payables p
  WHERE p.purdate >= in_startDate AND 
        p.purdate <= in_endDate;
END;
```

Comment: I tried it and it still returns `NULL`. P.S. Can I post a screenshot here?

Comment: I have updated the Question with screen captures of the recent changes as advised.